# Firebase anonymous user - Is the UUID secret?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, anonymous

I want to create an android app, which uses firebase as datastore and has users and groups of users. Each group has a list with the containing users unique user-id.

Is it a good idea to share the user-id to all group-members, if i use anonymous authentication? 
I mean, is the user-id the only credential, a device with anonymous anthentication logs in with to the firebase? If that would be so, some other could login with  another user id.

Comment: The value you're referring to is called a UID (short for User ID). It identifies a user, but does not authenticate them: knowing someone's UID does not allow you to authenticate as that user. So a UID can (and likely must) be shared freely without introducing a security risk. I've answered this before, so will look for the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me much!